# Как работать с сетью в Delphi?

Tags: linux, delphi, lazarus

Cреда разработки `Lazarus` (ОС Linux Debian Squeeze). Хочу написать приложение для Linux, работающее с сетью на Delphi. Подскажите литературу или какие-либо мануалы.

Answer (score 1):

На данный момент - лучший мануал это форумы. Вопрос в том, что вы хотите сделать с сеткой, просто использовать приложения aka icq, или что-то, что будет мультифункциональным?

lazarus отличается от делфи, это очевидно. Много нюансов, даже в элементарных вещах (как-то запуск стороннего приложения, в делфи одной командой, в лазаре кучей строчек).

***Линки***

[вот пособие Программирование в сетях Microsoft Windows. Мастер-класс](http://www.delphimaster.ru/books/978531800725/)

[сайт посвященный неким моментам моментам](http://www.ishodniki.ru/list/delphi/delphi_network/)